# Should individual tv or movies have its own tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should tags for individual movies be encouraged](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-tags-for-individual-movies-be-encouraged)

Should movies have their own individual tag?

e.g. If a movie is about inception does it really need its own [inception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inception) tag?

This is merely a question about how specific does a tag need to be.

Comment: Hi. I remembered that this had been discussed already - feel free to contribute an answer to the original question if you feel that the balance on tagging is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Tags do not merely form part of the content of the question - it is meta information that allows the question to be found more easily.

The purpose of tags to allow someone to search for questions of a particular topic.  You can have favorite tags which color the questions differently on the list, and you can have tag subscriptions - be emailed when questions about your topics of interest come up.

As a site about movies and TV, it seems reasonable to tag a question with the title of the movie or series it relates to.